# mailto:- Outlook is converting weblink %2F to a / can I stop this? Firebase Storage getDownloadURL()

Tags: firebase, outlook, firebase-storage, mailto

I am getting the downloadURL from firebase on file upload, after upload I want to email the link to various people.

I am using mailto: and outlook but the %2F in the downloadURL is being converted to a / which is stopping the link from working.

Example of link below. (The & in the link was also breaking the body so I replaced & with %26)

From - submittedFiles%2FSample.xlsx

To -   submittedFiles/Sample.xlsx
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myTestSite.appspot.com/o/submittedFiles%2FSample.xlsx?alt=media&token=XXX.

Any ideas on how I can solve this please.

This is a react-app

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where the `%2F` is being decoded, but you can typically fix such problems by once more encoding the `%2F` so that it becomes `%252F`. For seeing how to URL encode specific characters, see https://www.urlencoder.org/

Comment: That worked, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
 storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
            console.log("Success ", url)
            let downloadLink = url.replace("&", "%26")
            downloadLink = downloadLink.replace("%2F", "%252F")
            sendEmail(downloadLink);
        })
```

Thanks to Frank van Puffelen